# Rails app too many parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, filter, controller

I have a page with a list of items and above the list I have multiple links that act as filters.  Clicking on the links causes an ajax request to be fired with a whole host of URL parameters. Any example set of params after clicking a few filters:

```
?letters=a-e&page=1&sort=alphabetically&type=steel
```

It is all working fine but I feel like the params on the URL are very messy, and the code behind has to do alot of checking to see which params exist, merge new ones, overwrite existing ones etc.

Is there a nicer way to accomplish this without URL parameters.

I guess the downside to that would be the fact a user would not be able to link to a specific filtered view or is there a way this could be accomplished too?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options when working with long query strings. If this isn't really causing a problem (like requests dying) then you should ask yourself if it's really worth the effort to switch it to something else.

**Use POST Requests**

If the length of the query string is causing problem, you can switch to using POST requests instead of GET request from your filter links. That will prevent the URL from containing the filter parameters, but your controller can still deal with the parameters in the same way.

The `link_to` helper can be setup to use a different HTTP verb as follows:

```
link_to("My Filter", filter_path, method: :post)
```

Make sure you update your routes appropriately if you use this technique.

**Use an Ajax Request to Refresh the Page**

If you configure your filters to all be remote (Ajax) links, you can update the filters and refresh the **contents** of the page without ever changing the URL. This is the basic pattern of the solution:

- Send a remote request to the server with the current filter options
- Update the page contents based on those filters
- Make sure the filters (and remote request) will submit all of the current parameters again

**Store Filters in the User's Session**

If you store the current filters in the session, whenever the user visits the base page, you can retrieve the stored filters and only display the appropriate information. Your filter links could still be GET requests (including the lengthy query strings), but instead of rendering the page after the filter request, you would redirect back to the main list with no extra query parameters. That would make it appear to the user that the URL never changed, and would even allow you to remember their last filter if they navigate away.

**Sharing Links**

Like you mentioned, sharing links becomes a problem with all of these solutions. You can provide a "share this filter" section on the page to help mitigate that. You would put a URL the user could copy in that section that includes the necessary information to recreate the filter. The links could contain the full query string or perhaps an encoded version of the filter.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Not had chance to read through it yet but I will be. Thankyou so much.